# C# Asynchronous TCP socket communication crashes on 2.try over seperate computers at network

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous, tcp

I'm trying to develop an asynch TCP server-client application. In my application i'm using [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/fx6588te.aspx) article as a start point. I changed the code block for transfering serialized objects instead transfering string. And i'm transferring large data in this objects with several packages.

On my local machine everything fine: In the begining client connects, server accepts and they connected till i end. Client send request when i trig and starts to waiting data, server receives data, and server immidiately returns a result sending, client receives this result and operation is over. Whilst still system has connected, i'm trigging client again and the transaction is repeating. How many time i trig everything working fine.

But at any other intranet computer, client starts connection, server accepts and transaction works fine at first time.. But at the second try, server answering result but client application suspending at BeginReceive-EndReceive cycle...

What is wrong? Are there any nerwork limitation for asynch .net c# TCP socket infrastructure?

Answer (score 0):

Without code it's hard to say, but check your keepalive setting (try turning it off).

Comment: I considered that but since disabling keepalive is a possible resolution I figured I'd post it as an answer.